# Show these integers in each of these sets are pairwise relatively prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My thought process: the integers are pairwise relatively prime if all the gcd of that set of integers listed below are 1.

a) $\{31, 34, 55\}$

$\gcd(31,34) = 1$,
$\gcd(31,55) = 1$,
$\gcd(34,55) = 1$.

Answer: Yes, pairwise relatively prime

b) $\{14,17,85\}$

$\gcd(14,17) = 1,$
$\gcd(14,85) = 1,$
$\gcd(17,85) = 1.$

Answer: Yes, pairwise relatively prime

c) $\{25,41,49,64\}$

$\gcd(25,41) = 1,$
$\gcd(25,49) = 1,$
$\gcd(25,64) = 1,$
$\gcd(41,49) = 1,$
$\gcd(41,64) = 1$,
$\gcd(49,64) = 1$.

Answer: Yes, pairwise relatively prime

d) $\{7,8,9,1\}$

$\gcd(7,8) = 1,$
$\gcd(7,9) = 1,$
$\gcd(7,1) = 1,$
$\gcd(8,9) = 1,$
$\gcd(8,1) = 1,$
$\gcd(9,1) = 1.$

Answer: Yes, pairwise relatively prime

Is there a nice way to check the answers for any set of integers?

Comment: Note that $17$ divides $85$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah yes you are right!